# how to set-up a geofence for a specific rectangle?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to set-up a specific geofence for a rectangle using coordinates... if the user is in the geofence, I need to call an action.

Any ideas would help a lot! I also learn better from example code, or linking off to tutorials, or apple's examples.

Comment: @Rob you should make than an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when you say "geofence", you are talking about [Monitoring Shape-Based Regions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13) as discussed in the *Location Awareness Programming Guide.* If so, that document describes it a bit and the [Regions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010726) sample code might be helpful working demonstration.

Comment: Thanks man! This seems like the direction I need to go in, and thanks for replying so quickly!